# Convergence speed in Lévy’s continuity theorem

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

I suppose the answer to my question follows from the proof of the [Lévy’s continuity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem),
but probably one could suggest me a direct reference to the corresponding answer.

The question is as follows. Suppose the sequence of characteristic functions (c.f.) $\phi_n$ of random variables $X_n$ converge point-wise to some c.f. $\phi$ of random variable $X$ with convergence rate $\alpha(x,n)$, i.e. $\phi(x) = \phi_n(x) + O(\alpha(x,n))$ where $\alpha(x,n)$ tends to $0$ while $n$ tends to infinity. Does this implies that $P(X_n \leq x) = P(X \leq x) + O(\alpha(x,n))$?

Comment: You probably already now that convergence in distribution of $X_n$ to $X$ is equivalent to the convergence of cumulative distribution function at the points of continuity of $F_X$ (cdf of $X$). So here, convergence may fail when we consider $X$ with a non continuous cdf (for example, $X_n=1/n$ and $X=0$).

Comment: Thank you for your remark, but I am only interested in the case when cdfs of $X_n$ and $X$ are continious.

Comment: Yes, I guessed it was you had in mind. I will think on it.

Comment: I think you might get a faster answer to this on [math.se] or MO. Let me know if you want to migrate this to one of them. I can migrate it to [math.se] if you want, however, for MO we have to first check with them that the migration is fine.

Comment: @Kaveh: Yes, I suppose the question is more appropriate for Mathematics

Comment: So would you like the question migrated to [math.se]?

Comment: @Kaveh: Yes, I would.